# Exclude/limit to current year from Prompt values- Cogno BI 11

Tags: cognos-11

I have a prompt that allows users to select multiple years and provides data with each selected year as a column.  However, I would like to provide a singleton with an average for all prior years. So if the user selects 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020 on the prompt menu, I would like it to return an average for 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019.  Including 2020 would throw off the average.
I use the following expression to limit my data to the selected years, but how can I edit it to exclude the current year? #promptmany('PromptYear','memberuniquename','[All Years]','set(', '', ')')#
Or am I looking in the wrong place entirely??

Comment: Can you have a separate query that does not include the current year
Then perform the average?